# MySQL query to get most recent and cheapest items per classification

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate

I have a dataset that consists of prices for various rental cars.  The data consists of:

- Class of car (compact, minivan, suv etc),
- Price of rental, and
- date the data was collected.

I need to query this data to get the cheapest price per class, but I also need to select the most recent price from where there are several results in the database, even if the most recent one is more expensive than an older one.

For example I might have data like this:

- Class, Price, Date
- suv, 100, today
- suv, 121, today
- suv, 49, 3 days ago
- minivan, 89, yesterday
- minivan, 120, yesterday
- minivan, 100, yesterday
- minivan, 91, 3 days ago
- minivan, 77, 3 days ago
- etc

I want to run a query that will grab the following data:

- suv, 100, today
- minivan, 89, yesterday
- etc

If I do a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM data
ORDER BY class, date DESC, price;
```

then the topmost row per class contains the correct data.  I just need to know how I can get the database to return only those rows and discard the rest.

I'm using a rather heavily locked down MySQL database, and creating temporary tables is not an option.

Updated to add:

The above is a highly simplified version of the reql query that's being run.  The real query does joins across several tables and looks more like this:

```
SELECT hc.companyname AS supplier, 
sr.pricedetails AS price, 
sr.matchedsipp AS class,
sr.cardetails AS cardetails,
CAST(sj.jobdate AS DATE) AS jobdate 
FROM searchdetails sd 
STRAIGHT_JOIN searchresults sr ON (
    sd.taskid = sr.taskid 
    AND sd.locationid = sr.locationid 
    AND sd.jobid = sr.jobid 
    AND sd.companyid = sr.companyid
) 
JOIN hirecompanies hc ON sr.companyid = hc.companyid 
JOIN locations lc ON lc.locationid = sd.locationid 
JOIN searchjobs sj ON sr.jobid = sj.jobid 
WHERE DATE(sd.pudate) = '2010-12-28' 
AND DATE(sd.dodate) = '2011-01-04' 
AND hc.countrycode = 'GB' 
AND lc.iata = 'MAN';
```

pudate is pick-up date, and dodate is drop off date.  All temporal data is stored using DATETIME fields.

Comment: I'm not sure which price you want.  Do you want the cheapest price per class, or the most recent price per class?

Comment: I want the cheapest price from the most recent search per class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should produce the lowest price for the most recent search date per vehicle type:

```
 SELECT * FROM data D1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT * FROM data D2 WHERE D2.class = D1.class
                             AND (D2.date > D1.date 
                             OR (D2.date = D1.date AND D2.price < D1.price)))
```

How much data do you have (this will not be especially performant over a lot of data)?

Comment: Oops, edited to add the missing class condition in the correlated subquery.

Comment: The amount of data in question is fairly huge, and I've had to reject the other solutions so far on speed grounds.

Comment: In the end I had to use PHP to filter down a larger resultset because it was faster.  However this seems to be the most technically correct answer so you get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

How about using multiple SELECTs with a LIMIT 1, and then using a UNION? That way you can combine different ORDER BY's and still only get 1 row for each specific query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT class, date, MIN(price) 
FROM data 
WHERE (class, date) IN 
    (SELECT class, MAX(date) FROM data GROUP BY class)
```

Comment: Just ran a query to check, `IN` with multiple columns and multiple values works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  class, MAX(date) AS maxdate
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                class
        ) td
JOIN    mytable t
ON      t.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable ti
        WHERE   ti.class = td.class
                AND ti.date = td.maxdate
        ORDER BY
                ti.class, ti.date, ti.price, ti.id
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `mytable (class, date, price, id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: Hi Quassnoi, thanks for the response.  Your answer looks the most promising of the ones so far, but matters are complicated by the fact that the data I'm using is itself built from a query across a couple of joined tables.  The class and price come from a searchresults table, and the data from a searchjobs table, which records the date a given search job was last run.  Trying to figure out how to adapt the query I have to your suggestion now.

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest price per class

```
SELECT
*,
FROM data
GROUP BY class
HAVING date=max(date)
```

Lowest price would be the same except

```
HAVING price=min(price)
```

And then if you want least price when more than one have the latest date

```
HAVING date=max(date) AND price=min(price)
```